# InterviewBit Problem: Stringoholics

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, strings, time-limit-exceeded, interview-questions

I am trying to solve [this InterviewBit](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/stringoholics/) problem.

**Problem Statement:**

> You are given an array A consisting of strings made up of the letters
> ‘a’ and ‘b’ only. Each string goes through a number of operations,
> where:
>
> 1. At time 1, you circularly rotate each string by 1 letter.
> 2. At time 2, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by 2 letters.
> 3. At time 3, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by 3 letters.
> 4. At time i, you circularly rotate the new rotated strings by i % length(string) letters.
>
> Eg: String is "abaa"
>
> 1. At time 1, string is "baaa", as 1 letter is circularly rotated to the back
> 2. At time 2, string is "aaba", as 2 letters of the string "baaa" is circularly rotated to the back
> 3. At time 3, string is "aaab", as 3 letters of the string "aaba" is circularly rotated to the back
> 4. At time 4, string is again "aaab", as 4 letters of the string "aaab" is circularly rotated to the back
> 5. At time 5, string is "aaba", as 1 letters of the string "aaab" is circularly rotated to the back
>
> After some units of time, a string becomes equal to it’s original
> self. Once a string becomes equal to itself, it’s letters start to
> rotate from the first letter again (process resets). So, if a string
> takes t time to get back to the original, at time t+1 one letter will
> be rotated and the string will be it’s original self at 2t time. You
> have to find the minimum time, where maximum number of strings are
> equal to their original self. As this time can be very large, give the
> answer modulo 10<sup>9</sup>+7.
>
> Note: Your solution will run on multiple test cases so do clear global
> variables after using them.
>
> Input:
>
> A: Array of strings. Output:
>
> Minimum time, where maximum number of strings are equal to their
> original self. Constraints:
>
> 1 <= size(A) <= 10^5 1 <= size of each string in A <= 10^5 Each string
> consists of only characters 'a' and 'b' Summation of length of all
> strings <= 10^7

**But I got Time Limit Exceed Error.**

I followed the below approach:

> With respect to a single string, the total number of bits rotated
> after N operations is 1+2+3+….+N which is (N*(N+1))/2. We get back the
> original string only when the total number of rotated bits is a
> multiple of the length of the string S(LEN).
>
> This can be done in O(N) time for each string (Summation of length of
> all strings is <= 1e6), by finding all (N(N+1))/2 where N starts from
> 1 and goes upto (2LEN-1).
>
> But there is a catch, this wont always give you the minimum number of
> operations. Its possible that during rotation, you can get the
> original string before the number of bits rotated is a multiple of
> LEN.
>
> Example: S=> 100100 Here, in 2 operations, we get the original string
> back. This takes place because the string is made up of recurring
> substrings.
>
> Assume string A to be 100 S => AA Hence, over here our length S of
> string is the length of recurring substring A, so N*(N+1)/2 should be
> a multiple of length of A.
>
> Length of recurring substring can easily be found out using KMP
> algorithm in O(N) time complexity for each string.
>
> Find the minimum number of operations for each string, and take the
> LCM of all these values to get the answer.

My Solution:

```
#define MOD 1000000007

int findSmallestString(string A)
{
    int n = A.length();
    vector<int> lps(n + 1, 0);
    int index = 0, i = 1;
    
    while(i < n)
    {
        if(A[index] == A[i])
        {
            lps[i] = index + 1;
            index++;
            i++;
        } else
        {
            if(index != 0)
            {
                index = lps[index - 1];
            } else
            {
                lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    int t1 = lps[n - 1];
    int t2 = n - t1;
    
    if(t1 < t2 || (t1 % t2 != 0)) return n;
    
    return t2;
}

int Solution::solve(vector<string> &A) {
    int n = A.size();
    vector<int> v(n);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        long long len = findSmallestString(A[i]);
        long long k = 1;
        while(1)
        {
            long long rotates = (k * (k + 1)) / 2;
            if(rotates % len == 0)
            {
                v[i] = k;
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
    }
    
    long long ans = 1ll;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n && v[i] != 1; j++)
        {
            v[j] = v[j] / __gcd(v[i], v[j]);
        }
        
        ans = ((ans % MOD) * (v[i] % MOD)) % MOD;
    }
    
    return ans;
}
```

Is there any way to optimize the solution?

Comment: Please include the text of the code challenge in the question, links can break.

Comment: "its" not "it's" in "it’s original self".   "it's" is a contraction for "it is".

Comment: @JDlugosz while that [is the case](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/13148/213844) the OP was merely quoting [the source of the challenge](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/stringoholics/). Perhaps it would be more constructive to contact that organization.

Comment: It would be proper to insert ["[sic]"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sic) in the quoted passage.

Answer (score 2):

#### As you got TLA, you (probably) need a better algorithm:

1. Map from the strings to their periods.
2. Remove duplicates.
3. Map from string-periods to transformation-periods modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.
4. Determine LCM over them modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7.

#### Regarding implementation efficiency:

You allocate memory everywhere, for `std::string` and `std::vector`. Both are expensive, and also superfluous.

For functions expecting a string, see whether `std::string_view` will fit the deal. If it does it will even beat `std::string const&`.

#### Regarding standard conformance:

`__gcd()` is an implementation detail of your implementation. Just use `std::gcd()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MOD 1000000007
```

Don't use `#define`.  This should be

```
constexpr int MOD = 1000000007;
```

(and this is assuming that ints are big enough to hold that value!)

```
int findSmallestString(string A)
```

Why are you passing `A` by value, duplicating the string?  Write `const string&` as a matter of course; but use `string_view` for parameters when that makes sense.

```
int n = A.length();
```

You mean `size_t`, not `int`.  Is this going to change?  I think it should not; you should write

```
const auto n = A.length();
```

---

Later, you call it as

```
long long len = findSmallestString(A[i]);
```

So is it `int` or `long long`?  Again, I don't think you are modifying `len` after this so why isn't it `const`?

---

You seem to be missing all the `#include` statements, and maybe others, so this won't compile as-posted.  Please post complete examples.

Where does `__gcd` come from?  That is a reserved name, so I suppose some non-standard built-in.